# Is there any sense in use of Authorization Code Binding To DPoP Key when client is confidential and uses PKCE?

Tags: oauth2, openid-connect

[This spec](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-dpop-14.html) defined DPoP mechanism to bind cryptographically bind access tokens. There is also mention about authorization code binding.

But hey, do you see any sense in it? Ok, it obviously is a way to prevent authorization code injection attacks, but the PKCE does the same and is more light-weight.

What's more, the confidential client MUST be authenticated on `Pushed Authorization` and `Token` endpoints, so something like "binding to owner" also doesn't make any sense if PKCE is used.

But the [FAPI2.0 Security Profile](https://openid.net/specs/fapi-2_0-security-profile-03.html) says that authorization server:

> if using DPoP, shall support "Authorization Code Binding to DPoP Key" (as required by section 10.1 of [I-D.ietf-oauth-dpop]).

We know that FAPI2.0 handles only confidential clients. Why they require to support authorization code binding? Any pros of this approach?